# Why are particles set to scale 1.0 way bigger then my Original particle

Tags: particles, scale

Just wanna understand the logic behind it.

1. I create a cube.(Not changing scale or size)
2. I create a icosphere.(Not changing scale or size)
3. Create Hair particles, and set SCALE to 1.0.

Now my particles are way bigger, then the original.
(I found that around 0.25 scale is resulting in same size than the org.

Why is that?
What did I not understand?

Answer (score 3):

Final hair particle size is the result of multiplying hair length with particle object scale.

Default hair length is $4$ Blender Units, so to get an object of identical size to the original you have to multiply it by $1/4$, hence $0.25 \times 4 = 1$

If you plan on rendering particles as objects and need easy to set up scales then change hair length to $1$.